# How to set "Room Bounding" attribute on all elements in Revit API

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk, revit

I want to go over all elements in the document and set their "Room Bounding" attribute positive if they have a Room Bounding attribute.

Iterating the walls I can do this:

`Parameter param = e.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.WALL_ATTR_ROOM_BOUNDING).Set("Yes");`

However how do I do that for Columns? Or any other element who have this attribute?

I've tried going over all elements and get their parameters using:

`IList<Parameter> ps = e.GetOrderedParameters();`

but which attribute do I look for? is it "Room Bounding"? Do I set it to "Yes" or any other thing?

Edit: 
I first started with this:
https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/09/selecting-all-w.html
adjusting the code to retrive the Room Bounding parameter.

Then changing my code to support all elements, as my question mentioned and using:
https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/05/getting-all-parameter-values.html

And I've used it to print all parameters names and their value, however I can't find the Room Bounding parameter in columns.
I could easily do it in walls.

I tried using 
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/get-the-value-of-shared-a-parameter-of-a-structural-column/td-p/8249860
and using

`mycolumnList[i].LookupParameter("Room Bounding").AsInteger() != 1)`

but this also didn't work.

Should I look for "Room Bounding" in instance parameter or in type parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'll post a solution to help others who had similar issue.

Given an column e the following code change the "Room Bounding" parameter to True.
(Please notice this code do not handle exceptions)

```
FamilyInstance famInst = e as FamilyInstance;
Parameter family_bound_param = famInst.LookupParameter("Room Bounding");
if (family_bound_param.AsValueString() == "No")
{                           
    using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "param"))
    {
        t.Start();
        family_bound_param.Set(1);
        t.Commit();
    }
}
```

Thanks Jeremy for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow
the [standard approach to research and solve a Revit API programming task](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#3):

1. Determine the optimal solution manually through the end user interface. Make sure you follow best practices and make use of existing built-in Revit functionality. If you skip this step or do not research deeply enough, you run a large risk of programming something that will be painful both to implement, maintain, debug and use.
2. Determine the names of the Revit classes, methods and properties that will help you achieve your task. For example, create the appropriate situation and sample BIM via the user interface and analyse it before and after making the modifications you need, e.g., using:

   - [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup)
   - [BipChecker](https://github.com/jeremytammik/BipChecker)
   - [The element lister](https://github.com/jeremytammik/AdnRevitApiLabsXtra)
   - [Other, more intimate Revit database exploration tools](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/11/intimate-revit-database-exploration-with-the-python-shell.html),  such as the Revit Python or Ruby shell
3. Once you know what Revit API objects are required, learn how to access, manipulate and drive them, their relationships and how they interact with each other:

   - Revit API help file `RevitAPI.chm` installed locally or [online at revitapidocs.com](http://www.revitapidocs.com) provides detailed info on classes, properties and methods.
   - [Revit online help](http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2017/ENU) > Developers > [Revit API Developers Guide](http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-F0A122E0-E556-4D0D-9D0F-7E72A9315A42) explains the Revit API usage in much more depth and provides invaluable background information.
   - Revit SDK sample collection installed locally and managed by Visual Studio via `SDKSamples.sln` shows how Revit API objects work together to solve specific tasks.
   - [The Building Coder samples](https://github.com/jeremytammik/the_building_coder_samples) provide another large bunch of sample external commands implementing numerous different tasks.

After you have exhausted those options, search the Internet for 'revit api' or 'thebuildingcoder' plus the Revit API names that you are interested in.

I very much hope that this addresses your question in full and does not only feed you for the moment, but also supports you in the process of being transformed into a competent future fisherman.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,

I'm going over The Building Coder samples and explanations regulary and they helped allot. 
I can already do allot within Revit API and I'm always learning however I couldn't figure this specific issue and couldn't find this answer online (even tho there are a few close examples).

I've edit my question to give a better idea of what I've already tried.

I understand you don't want to feed me with the answer however your answer was a bit to general for my problem.
Could you point me in a more specific direction?

Comment: Hi Raz, glad to hear The Building Coder is useful and helped. Unfortunately, I cannot be more specific due to lack of knowledge. I would suggest that you ask the architectural end user experts for help on how this can be solved manually in the end user interface. Once you have got that part sorted out, it is time to step up into the programming environment and research how to achieve the same result programmatically through the API.

Comment: That is part of the standard approach I refer to above. I cannot imagine any other way to proceed, since the programmers never know all the detailed intricacies of advanced BIM modelling.

Comment: In general, if a feature is not available in the Revit product manually through the user interface, then the Revit API will not provide it either. You should therefore research the optimal workflow and best practices to address your task at hand manually through the user interface first. To do so, please discuss and analyse it with an experienced application engineer, product usage expert, or product support.

Comment: Please let us know how you end up solving this in case anyone else runs into the same question. Thank you!

Comment: I think that approach (solved it manually in end user interface) is what I did, first I've selected all the elements in a given floor plan (by selecting over with my mouse), then on the left side (properties) window, I selected Walls, 'tick' their "Room Bounding" parameter. Then I've selected Columns and also turned on their "Room Bounding" parameter. When trying to do it by code (going all elements, trying  to turn on their Room bounding parameter it only works for walls and not columns).

Comment: So maybe the question is: while I can see the parameter "Room Bounding" in the user interface under walls and columns,  why I can only access this in walls and not columns in the API?

Comment: Have you installed RevitLookup and examined the column properties? Using that you should be able to find out where the column setting is stored when you manipulate them manually through the end user interface. https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup